# UK: What are my rights if i'm woken by construction work, or roadworks at night?

Tags: united-kingdom, health, noise

A while back I was woken by some workmen repairing metal railings on the side the road next to my house.

This occurred at around 1:30 am, I brashly asked the workmen to stop. To which they complied.

If a similar incident occurs in the future, what are my rights when asking them to stop?

Answer (score 3):

You are free to ask them to stop.

If they do, great.

If they don’t, you legal options depend on if they are legally able to make such noise at that time or not.

I am not familiar with UK law but typical laws give wide powers to the owners of infrastructure to construct/repair it. Again, typically, permits may be required but exceptions exist for urgent work. If they have such a permit (or don’t need one) your legal options are nil. If they don’t you can go to court seeking an injunction to stop them until they do.

Comment: The normal procedure would be to complain to the local council. They are able to serve a notice without going to court. https://www.gov.uk/guidance/noise-nuisances-how-councils-deal-with-complaints#noise-from-construction-works

Comment: @richardb I sort of read it like it was the local council doing the work